# How can I view the source code of BaseDexClassLoader.class in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-source

I have downloaded the source code in sdk manager. It's seems like that the source code didn't contains this class. 
[image: no BaseDexClassLoader.java]

Here is BaseDexClassLoader.class which I cant see the source code:

[image: basedexclassloader.class]

and here is normal classes:

[image]

So how can I view the source code of classes like `BaseDexClassLoader.class` in Android Studio? I'm now watching it at `androidxref.com` but it's not so convenient.

Answer (score 1):

You can browse AOSP source code in https://cs.android.com ("official" AOSP code browser made by google ).

Here's the source code of BaseDexClassLoader.java ( from AOSP master branch ): https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:libcore/dalvik/src/main/java/dalvik/system/BaseDexClassLoader.java;l=1?q=BaseDexClassLoader.java&sq=&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject

If Google decided not to bundle that class in sources of SDK,you can always copy that class manually, and put in in the sources folder, so Android Studio can refer to it

Comment: And copy the source .java file to Android-SDK/sources/sdk-version/target-package-directory make it readable in Android Studio